# JPA query with 'And' in the variable name

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, repository

```
findAllByBoolVariable1AndBoolAndVariable2AndBoolVariable3
```

I have a query like this. The entity variable names are `boolVariable1`, `boolAndVariable2` (has an 'And' in its name) and `boolVariable3`.

I get the error "No property bool found for type ..." on building.

I cannot be removing the 'And' in the variable name.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: IMHO there is no way to make this work. You will have to write a query

Comment: `findAllByBoolVariable1AndBoolAndVariable2AndBoolVariable3` i think also in this mistake is like that `findAllByBoolVariable1AndBoolVariable2AndBoolVariable3`

Answer (score 1):

Loook at this examplle:

```
@Query("select r from EntityName r where r.boolAndVariable2 = :param")
List<EntityName> findByVariable(@Param("param") String param);
```

You can use @Query annotation and in write your query in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom `Query` with the help of annotation @Query

```
@Transactional
     @Query("delete from LogicCondition lc where lc.id = :id")
     void deleteById(Integer id);
```

for like that!